# Format representing 0 with '-' not working in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

I have applied a format in a cell to show 0 with '-' but when I took preview it shows me 0 instead of '-'. Whats problem with that format.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLpAD.png)

Comment: It's possible that your dataset is bringing in the data as a string datatype.  Check that the data is a numeric datatype and if not, `CInt([yourField].Value)`.

Comment: yes thanks that works for me...

Comment: But my Question is why ssrs doesn't treat value to integer although  I have typed 0 in cell

Comment: I believe that text entered into a textbox is by default interpreted as a string.  Try typing in `=0` and formatting the zero to show as a dash and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look in your sql select if your data type is a string or an integer. Then convert or dont into the sql script.

I hope it helps. Regards!